# Comparison is always false due to limited range of data type trying to saturate colors

Tags: c, colors, warnings, compiler-warnings, mandelbrot

I'm trying to saturate my colors and make sure they do not overflow
   so that they will draw a pretty Mandlebrot set without being pixelated.
I'm using an Altera DE2 board to try and print this Mandlebrot set via VGA connection to a computer screen and the colors are slightly off (pixely).

How exactly do I correct the if statements in the code below to not always be false?

```
if (iteration == 500)
{
    alt_up_pixel_buffer_dma_draw(my_pixel_buffer,0,0,0);
}
else
{
    //double z = sqrt(xtemp * xtemp + y * y);
    //int brightness = 256. * log2(1.75 + i - log2(log2(z))) / log2(500);
    //color(brightness, brightness, 255);
    //color is some function of iteration
    alt_u8 Red = (iteration*8);///zoom);
    if(Red > 255) // this if statement is always false
        Red = 255;

    alt_u8 Green = (iteration*4);///zoom);
    if(Green > 255) // this if statement is always false
        Green = 255;

    alt_u8 Blue = (iteration*2);///zoom);
    if(Blue > 255) // this if statement is always false
        Blue = 255;

    //draw the pixels
    alt_up_pixel_buffer_dma_draw(my_pixel_buffer, (Blue) + (Green<<8) + (Red<<16),j,i);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: sorry, thank you. I'm looking to possibly understand why or how to fix the if statements in the code to not always yield a false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a larger integer to get the result of the multiplication, so you can test if it exceeds the limit.

```
alt_u8 Red;
uint16_t tempRed = iteration * 8;
if (tempRed > 255) {
    Red = 255;
} else {
    Red = tempRed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the maximum value that can be stored in an `alt_u8` is 255, there's no point checking whether it holds a larger value.  (You would not be getting the warning if that were not the case, even though the type of `alt_u8` is not visible.)

However, it also means that your assignments are dangerous because the assigned value is stored modulo 256.  You probably need to use:

```
alt_u32 new_Red = iteration * 8;  // Guessed type; uint32_t or uint16_t would do
alt_u8 Red = new_Red;
if (new_Red > 255)
    Red = 255;
```

Now the value in `new_Red` can exceed 255, but the assignments ensure the saturated value is stored, rather than `new_Red % 256` which would be stored otherwise.